# Intellij doesn't recognize my step definitions

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-serenity

I'm upgrading a cucumber project to cucumber 6. But after the upgrade intellij doesn't recognize my steps anymore. When I run via my pom there is no issue. But if you try to go to the step definition from the feature file intellij says that there is no stepdefintion

My runner is like this

```
package be.nbb.hive.cucumber;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty"},
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = {"be.nbb.hive.cucumber.Steps"}
)
public class CucumberTestSuite {}
```

And my steps are in the package

```
package be.nbb.hive.cucumber.Steps;
```

Is this the issue or is it something else that blocks the recognision?

Comment: Maybe you can invalidate cache and restart intelliJ?

Comment: That did not resolve it

Comment: Maybe some addition the issue started after upgrding to cucumber6 and the latest version of serenity

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Installing [`cucumber for java`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7212-cucumber-for-java) and [`gherkin`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9164-gherkin) IntelliJ plugins from marketplace resolved it for me

Comment: I have both already installed